# What does this mean in Linux sed '$a\' a.txt

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have this line in my Linux shell script

```
sed '$a\' < file_a.txt
```

Afraid to remove it from the code and cannot find out what it is for.

Comment: perhaps there is a space after the `\`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It makes sure the output will end with a newline; see:

```
echo -ne test | sed '$a\'
# same output as:
echo test | sed '$a\'
```

As you can see with the previous code, a carriage return isn't added in the second example but one is added in the first example. Of course, if you remove the `sed` part, the output will be different since the first `echo` statement has no carriage return.