# how to use sed to replace the specific line/lines in a file with the contents from another file

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace several lines in one of my files with the contents (which consists of the same lines) from another file which is located in another folder with the `sed` command.

For example: `file1.txt` is in `/storage/file` folder, and it looks like this:

```
'ABC'
'EFG' 001
HJK
```

`file2.txt`is located in `/storage` folder, and it looks like this:

```
'kkk' 123456789
yyy
```

so I want to use the content of `file2.txt` (which is one line) to replace the 2nd and 3rd line of `file1.txt`, and `file1.txt' should become like this:

```
'ABC'
'kkk' 123456789
yyy
```

---

I probably should make my questions more clear. So I'm trying to write a shell script which can be used to change several lines of a file (let's call it `old.txt`) with the new contents that I supplied in other files (which only contains the contents to be updated to the old file, for example, these files are `dataA.txt`,`dataB.txt`...... ).
Let's say, I want to replace the 3rd line of `old.txt` which is:

```
'TIME_STEPS' 'TIME CYCLE' 'ELAPSED' 100 77760 0 1.e+99 1. 9999 1. 1.e-20 1.e+99
```

with the new data that I supplied in `dataA.txt` which is:

```
'TIME_STEPS' 'TIME CYCLE' 'ELAPSED' 500 8520 0 1.e+99 1. 9999 1. 1.e-20 1.e+99
```

and to replace the 15th to 18th lines of the `old.txt` file which looks like:

```
100 0 1
101 1 2
102 2 1.5
103 4 52
```

with the supplied `dataB.txt' file which looks like (also contain 4 lines):

```
-100
-101
-102
-103
```

As I'm totally new to shell script programming, and I only used `sed`before, I tried the following command:
to change the 3ed line, I did `sed -i '3c r ../../dataA.txt' old.txt`, `r ../../dataA.txt` is to find the location of `dataA.txt`. However, as `c` needs to be followed by the content that to be changed rather the path of the content that to be changed. so I'm not very sure how to correctly use `sed`. Another idea that I'm thinking is to insert the `dataA.txt` ,`dataB.txt`... in front of the line that I want to modify and then deleted the old lines. But I'm still not sure how to do it after I googled for so long...

Comment: file2 is not just one line.

Comment: sorry, file2 has two lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace a range of lines with entire contents of another file:

```
sed -e '15r file2' -e '15,18d' file1
```

To replace a single line with entire contents of another file:

```
sed -e '2{r file2' -e 'd}' file1
```

If you don't know whether `file2` ends in newline or not, you can use the below trick (see [What does this mean in Linux sed '$a\' a.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41343062)):

```
sed '$ a\' file2 | sed -e '3{r /dev/stdin' -e 'd}' file1
```

The main trick is to use `r` command to add contents from the other file for the starting line address. And then delete the line(s) to be replaced. The `-e` option is needed because everything after `r` will be treated as filename.

Note that these have been tested with `GNU sed`, I'm not sure if it will vary for other implementations.

See my [github repo](https://github.com/learnbyexample/learn_gnused/blob/master/gnu_sed.md#adding-content-from-file) for more examples, such as matching lines based on regex instead of line numbers.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that there a problem with the code: when the contents of `file2` in your code got placed in the old line in `file1` and the old line got deleted, the line below will just move up. For example, in my case, I used your code to change the 3rd line of `old.txt` to the desired contents, but the 4th line of `old.txt`, which is `'-'`, just moved up to the 3rd line and appended to the new contents of 3rd line. Maybe a `\n` need to be placed somewhere?

Comment: @YueLiu that'll happen if `file2` doesn't end with newline character

Comment: can you try `sed 'a\' file2 | sed -e '3{r /dev/stdin' -e 'd}' file1`

Answer (score 0):

It is trivial with `ed`

```sh
printf '%s\n' '2,$d' 'r /storage/file2.txt' ,p Q | ed -s /storagefile/file1.txt
```

A syntax that should work with more variety of Unix shells.

```sh
 printf '2,$d\nr /storage/file2.txt\n,p\nQ\n' | ed -s /storage/file/file1.txt
```

---

- `2,$d` means `2` and `$` are the line addresses, 2 is line 2 and `$` is the last line in the buffer and `d` means delete.
- `,p` means print everything to `stdout` which is your screen.
- `Q` means silence the error which `q` will not.

---

With `ed` to change line 3 of a file with another content of a file, without using shell variables.

First delete the content of line 3 of the file.

```sh
printf '%s\n' '3d' ,p Q | ed -s file1.txt
```

Then add the content of the other file, say `file2.txt` at line 3.

```sh
printf '2r file2.txt' ,p Q | ed -s file1.txt
```

To replace a group/set of lines in a file with the content of another file.

First delete the lines, say 15 to 18 from say file1.txt

```sh
printf '%s\n' '15,18d' ,p Q | ed -s file1.txt
```

Then add the content of say file2.txt to line 15 of file1.txt

```
printf '%s\n' '14r file2.txt' ,p Q | ed -s file1.txt
```

The `Q` does not edit anything replace it with `w` to edit files.
The `r` appends so `14 r` means append the content of another file after line 14 which makes it line 15. Same is true with `2 r` append to line 2 which makes it line 3.

---

Also all of that can be done with one line, this code was adopted with your data/files names. Also this assumes that all the text file are in the same directory where you will run the code below, otherwise add the absolute path of the files in question.

```sh
printf '%s\n' '3d' '2r dataA.txt' '15,18d' '14r dataB.txt' ,n Q | ed -s old.txt
```

- Replace the `Q` with `w` If you're satisfied with the output and if you want to actually edit the `old.txt`
- the `,n` prints everything to `stdout` which is your screen but with  a line number at the front.
- To have an idea of what the actual code is being pipe to `ed` remove or comment out the pipe `|` and all the code after that.
- See `info ed` or `man ed` for more info about `ed`

---

An example of that `ed` script.

Create a new directory and `cd` into it.

```sh
mkdir temp && cd temp
```

```
cat dataA.txt
```

Output

```
'TIME_STEPS' 'TIME CYCLE' 'ELAPSED' 500 8520 0 1.e+99 1. 9999 1. 1.e-20 1.e+99
```

```
cat dataB.txt
```

Output

```
-100
-101
-102
-103
```

```
cat old.txt
```

Output

```
foo
bar
'TIME_STEPS' 'TIME CYCLE' 'ELAPSED' 100 77760 0 1.e+99 1. 9999 1. 1.e-20 1.e+99
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
100 0 1
101 1 2
102 2 1.5
103 4 52
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
```

The script.

```sh
printf '%s\n' '3d' '2r dataA.txt' '15,18d' '14r dataB.txt' ,n w | ed -s old.txt
```

Output

```
1       foo
2       bar
3       'TIME_STEPS' 'TIME CYCLE' 'ELAPSED' 500 8520 0 1.e+99 1. 9999 1. 1.e-20 1.e+99
4       a
5       b
6       c
7       d
8       e
9       f
10      g
11      h
12      i
13      j
14      k
15      -100
16      -101
17      -102
18      -103
19      l
20      m
21      n
22      o
23      p
24      q
25      r
26      s
27      t
28      u
29      v
30      w
31      x
32      y
33      z
```

The actual `old.txt`

```
cat old.txt
```

Output

```
foo
bar
'TIME_STEPS' 'TIME CYCLE' 'ELAPSED' 500 8520 0 1.e+99 1. 9999 1. 1.e-20 1.e+99
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
-100
-101
-102
-103
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
```

Comment: Is it possible to do with `sed`? As there are several lines that I want to change in my file with new contents and their formats are different. I tried to use the `sed -i c` to change the line but cannot correctly quote the content of the file2.txt.

Comment: `c` means replace or change the whole line, with something, but you need the line address or pattern and the replacement.

Comment: @YueLiu can you add the complete command you tried to the question? Click **edit** button below the question. Also, mention which `sed` version you have, `GNU sed` or something else.

Comment: @Jetchisel Yeah I realized that. I just made my question more clear, would you please have a look at it? Thanks!

Comment: @Jetchisel Thank you so much! Gonna check out the `ed`